# Hard disk is not recognized by BIOS after a clean in recovery mode of UBUNTU!

Tags: boot, 18.04, hard-drive, bios, recovery-mode

My laptop had a dual boot with windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04LTS. My Ubuntu partition was low on space, when I tried to boot into ubuntu system it showed some error which suggested that I was low on space in the Ubuntu partition. I went to the recovery mode and did a clean after which the pc tried to restart but the GRUB menu did not show up for about half an hour. I went to the BIOS screen and found that the BIOS was not detecting the hard drive which had all my research data, projects and documents.

Is there a way to recover my data?
Is it because of a fault in my hard drive or a fault in the ubuntu cleanup?

PS: My laptop has an SDD which has windows installed, all the data was kept in the HDD along with the ubuntu partition.

Comment: What does "did a clean" mean, specifically?

Comment: In the recovery menu there is an option: "clean       Try to make free space". I selected that option.

Answer (score 1):

Came to the conclusion that my hardisk was corrupted due to a bad sector. Had to change the hardisk.

PS: Never use a single hardisk for multiple boots. if possible try to use 2 hardisks. Don't go multibooting if you have a RAID configuration. It will suck in the long run.